# uploading to amazon s3 using lftp

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, ftp

Is it possible to upload files from an ftp to an amazon s3 bucket using lftp?

I tend to run this from an ec2 instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, S3 isn't exposed via an FTP interface.

What you can do is use [S3FS](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) to mount the filesystem in an EC2 instance. If you specifically wanted FTP for some reason then you could configure your FTP server with the directory root of the S3FS mount.

Answer (score 0):

S3 isn't really designed as a filestore, more of 'block store'. This means that while you can store files, there is no 'filesystem' that you will be used to- e.g. directories etc are not possible.

It is more likely that you want to use EBS, unless you have a very specific reason for using S3. EBS can be mounted to a running instance, which in turn can run an FTP server, which will allow you to use an S3 client.

If you just want to store things on S3 for your own personal use, consider using something like http://www.dropbox.com, which backs its storage on encrypted S3 volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend s2fox http://www.s3fox.net/. This is a plug in for firefox that allows you to upload, download and synchronize file to all your S3 buckets. It works really well for me.